# Async File IO under Unix and finding out how many bytes are left

Tags: c++, c, unix, file-io, asynchronous

I'm doing asynchronous file I/O under unix using open/close/etc.  I have everything working fine and I'm able to initiate background reads and writes and wait for them to finish using a select.

I have one issue left, however.  I would like to find out how much data is left to read/write.
Now I assume this is an easy ioctl call but I can find very little useful documentation on the whole thing :(

Anyone who can help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing reads from a standard file, you could use lseek using SEEK_CUR and a value of 0 for the offset to get the current file position, and then lseek to the end to get the end of file position and subtract them.

Not sure how you would know how much data is left to write, since you are the one writing it.  That would depend on your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably tell.

For example, another program may be adding data to the end of the file you are reading.

The "file" may in fact be a local or network pipe and not a file at all. In this case the data only ends when the pipe closes.

That said, you can find the total number of bytes in a file (if it *is* a file) using `fstat()` on the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Solaris fstat will return the number of bytes in a pipe.  Other unixes do not.

Also,

```
S_ISFIFO(st.st_mode)
```

will tell you if the open stream is a pipe or not, where st is a struct stat. This is true  on all unix flavors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fcntl()` to set your socket/pipe to non-blocking.  All calls `read()`  will then read available data, and calls to `write()` will write as much as possible without blocking.  In both cases the amount of data read/written is in the return value.

Example without any error checking:

```
    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Then after your `select()` and for all notified handles, call something like:

```
    if (buffer_sent < buffer_size)
        buffer_sent += write(socket, buffer+buffer_sent, buffer_size - buffer_sent);
```

Just to reiterate before I get flamed: a complete solution would include error checking.

Googling around for "non-blocking I/O" will lead to more fully worked examples :)